# How to list all network links in all namespaces in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ip, containers, linux-namespaces

As I know, in a Linux shell environment, I could list the networks links in any specific namespace with `ip`, like:

`ip netns exec <namespace> ip link show`

My question is:

If I have multiple net namespaces, how to list all the links in all the namespaces with a simple command? Or I have to write a script to do so?

Answer (score 7):

You can simply do:

```
ip link show; ip -all netns exec ip link show
```

Internally this just does what your script would do - it steps through all namespaces and runs the command.

Comment: Would you let me know your OS and version? I tried on both my Debian and CentOS, both get:
Option "-all" is unknown, try "ip -help".
And my version:
ip utility, iproute2-ss140804

Comment: I'm not sure which versions of iproute2 are included with which oses, but the -all option was introduced around February 2015 ( so around the official 4.0.0 release... not checked exactly which. ) Look for updated iproute2 packages. Otherwise you'll have to use a script.